# NUXT plugins CSS is not loading on production

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo, vue-apollo

I am using Nuxt with apollo for a project, Everything is working perfectly on a local server but on the live server, the CSS is broken for the plugins I used. I used these two plugins

1. vue-awesome-swiper
2. v-lazy-image

   ```
   plugins: [
   { src: "~/plugins/vue-awesome-swiper", mode: "client" },
   { src: "~/plugins/v-lazy-image", mode: "client" }],
   ```

Here is a live demo [chatfata.com](https://chatfata.com). as you can see the slider is broken and blur effect in not removing after the image is render.

I am facing one more problem maybe its related to this as it's my first time using Graphql with NUXT. 
On the live server, `npm run build` is not working. it gives some kind of `node_modules/babel-loader/lib??` no recognizing the. .gql extension as you can see the screenshot

[image]

So I do `npm run build` on local server and upload the files to live server. I don't if both errors are related

I need help
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MarineLeBorgne Yes, I solved both problems. Which prob you are facing. the CSS or module not found?

Comment: The external CSS not loading!

Comment: @AmirUrRehman how did you solve that the external css is not loading in prod?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command below:

```
npm install babel-loader @babel/core
```

And then run:

```
npm install && npm run build
```